# UILocalNotification Scheduling with Repeat for 10AM GMT Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I'm sorry if this is an absolute noob question, but I can't figure this one out from the documentation or other stack questions -

How can I set an NSDate object to 10:00AM GMT? The reason I ask is this - I want to set a localnotification to occur at 10:00AM GMT every day.

I think the following is on the right track:

```
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[comps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

[comps setYear:2011];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setWeek:1];
[comps setDay:1];
[comps setHour:10];
[comps setMinute:52];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

notif.fireDate = date;
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
notif.alertBody = @"New Challenges are available in Halo: Reach.\n\n Give them a look over with Halo Reach Challenges!";
notif.alertAction = @"Show Me";
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5;
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
[notif release];
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't fire. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your app is running, the notification is sent directly to your app. You'll need to set up a handler (in appDelegate) and the display the message yourself. When the app is not running, the notification should be shown.

Comment: Ok. I'm assuming there'll be a protocol reference linked in the UILocalNotification documentation. All I have to do is show a UIAlertView with the intended message, right?

Comment: Ok, and if I set it to a date in the past, with the repeat on... It fires instantly but then the replay interval should still work, right? Or will I have to get today's date, split it and add a day?

Comment: the former (the fact that it fires instantly on dates in the past) is explicitly mentioned in the documentation. There is, however, no notice what happens on the repetitions. I would expect them to function normally (that means, independent from the original being in the past or in the future), but that should be easy to check.

Comment: Yeha, it works as expected. I tested it out with NSMinuteTimeInterval. Thanks for all your help. I decided not to show a UILocalNotification though - the app is very, very... focused, and I know that my users are very focused as well. They wouldn't have the app open if they didn't want to check the data.